# Software like Samsung Galaxy Contacts

Tags: android, contact-manager

I am using Android Copperhead OS and I can't find a good contacts app. I had a look at a friends Samsung Galaxy Contacts app and it would be exactly what I want, but it is not available for my OS. Can you recommend an app that is as similar as possible?

Especially I like the emphasis on groups. Specifically what I'd like:

- having an own group tap,
- you can add, remove groups from multiple users at the same time,
- being able to move contacts from one account to another,
- having a favourites tap,
- being able to edit contacts,
- find duplicates but have me merge them manually, but help me to merge them in a guided fashion,
- full text search.

I don't need so much connections to social media and I don't want that my contacts are uploaded to some server (if this is just an option I don't have to use it I guess). I would prefer to have no advertising (obviously).

Comment: While waiting for recommendations, you might wish to check with my app listings on [Contact Managers and Dialers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_dialer). Some are explicitly markes for supporting dupe-find & merge, for example.

Comment: Did you consider buying a Samsung Galaxy  ?  :-)

Comment: @Mawg: I am using Copperhead OS on purpose ;-).